# Ordenação de uma lista não ordenada não funciona

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

O código funciona até a parte que eu tendo ordenar uma lista já criada usando uma nova lista, só que não consigo identificar o erro. Foi Quando eu criei as funções **Ordenar** e **AddOrdenado** que começou a dar erro.

OBS:Pedi para imprimir a nova lista no próprio **Ordenar** para poder testar, depois eu iria passar para o main, só que nem isso está funcionando.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Elemento{
  int valor;
  struct Elemento*prox;
}Elemento;

typedef struct Lista{
  Elemento*Inicio;
  Elemento*Fim;
}Lista;

Lista*CriandoLista(){
  Lista*lista=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
  lista->Inicio=NULL;
  lista->Fim=NULL;
  return lista;
}

Elemento*CriandoElemento(int n){
  Elemento*novo=(Elemento*)malloc(sizeof(Elemento));
  novo->prox=NULL;
  novo->valor=n;
  return novo;
}

void AddLista(Lista*lista,Elemento*novo){
  if(lista->Inicio==NULL){
      lista->Inicio=novo;
      lista->Fim=lista->Inicio;
  }else{
      lista->Fim->prox=novo;
      lista->Fim=novo;
  }
}

void Imprimir(Lista*lista){
  Elemento*aux=lista->Inicio;
  while(aux!=NULL){
      printf(" %d ",aux->valor);
      aux=aux->prox;
  }
}

void AddOrdenado(Lista*lista,Lista*nvlista){
  Lista*aux=lista;
  Lista*aux2=nvlista;
  if(nvlista->Inicio==NULL){
      nvlista->Inicio=lista->Inicio;
      nvlista->Fim=lista->Inicio;
      lista->Inicio=lista->Inicio->prox;
      nvlista->Inicio->prox=NULL;

  }else{
      if((nvlista->Inicio->valor)<(lista->Inicio->valor)){
          nvlista->Inicio=lista->Inicio;
          lista->Inicio=lista->Inicio->prox;
          nvlista->Inicio->prox=aux2->Inicio;
      }else if((nvlista->Fim->valor)>(lista->Inicio->valor)){
          aux2->Fim->prox=lista->Inicio;
          nvlista->Fim=aux2->Fim;
          lista->Inicio=lista->Inicio->prox;
          nvlista->Fim->prox=NULL;
      }else{
          while(aux2!=NULL){
              if((lista->Inicio->valor)>(aux2->Inicio->prox->valor)){
                  lista->Inicio->prox=aux2->Inicio->prox;
                  aux2->Inicio->prox=lista->Inicio;
                  lista->Inicio=aux->Inicio->prox;
              }
              aux2->Inicio=aux2->Inicio->prox;
          }
      }
  }
}
void Ordenar(Lista*lista){
  Lista*nvlista=CriandoLista();
  while(lista->Inicio!=NULL){
      AddOrdenado(lista,nvlista);
  }
  Imprimir(nvlista);
}

int main(){
  Lista*lista=CriandoLista();
  int n[]={5,10,9};
  for(int i=0;i!=sizeof(n)/sizeof(int);i++){
    AddLista(lista,CriandoElemento(n[i]));
  }
  Imprimir(lista);
  Ordenar(lista);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem várias coisas que precisa de acertar para que fique com a adição a funcionar.

- A sua função `Ordenar` nem sequer avança pelos nós:

  ```
  Lista*nvlista=CriandoLista();
  while(lista->Inicio!=NULL){
      AddOrdenado(lista,nvlista);
  }
  ```

  Repare que não existe nenhum `x = x->prox;`, logo isto é para todos os efeitos um `while` infinito, que é na verdade o problema que você vê diretamente na consola, pois ele não termina.

  Mas mesmo ainda nesta função tem outro problema que é mais subtil e mais complicado de resolver. Esse é o alterar dos `->prox` dos elementos da lista antiga. Se está a adicionar elementos da list antiga para a nova e troca o `->prox` a lista antiga deixa de funcionar, pois já não existem as ligações que deviam. Consegue resolver esse problema facilmente se adicionar uma cópia do nó em que vai, de forma a não invalidar a lista antiga. Posto isto tudo pode reescrever a sua função da seguinte forma:

  ```
  void Ordenar(Lista *lista) {
      Lista *nvlista=CriandoLista();
      Elemento *no_atual = lista->Inicio; //elemento para navegar na lista
      while(no_atual != NULL) {
          Elemento *novo = CriandoElemento(no_atual->valor); //adicionar uma cópia
          AddOrdenado(nvlista, novo);
          no_atual = no_atual->prox; //avançar para o proximo, que faltava
      }
      Imprimir(nvlista);
  }
  ```
- No `AddOrdenado` tem uma lógica muito mais complexa do que necessário e nem sequer contempla todos os casos particulares que existem. Sugiro outra aproximação que navegue pelos nós enquanto eles são menores que o nó a inserir, e que pare no primeiro nó maior. A inserção deve ser feita então no nó anterior ao que parou. Naturalmente tem de considerar casos particulares de lista vazia, ou nó maior/menor que todos.

  Seguindo essa lógica poderia fazer assim:

  ```
  void AddOrdenado(Lista *nvlista, Elemento *elemento) {
      if (nvlista->Inicio == NULL){ //se lista vazia
          nvlista->Inicio = nvlista->Fim = elemento;
          return;
      }

      Elemento *atual = nvlista->Inicio;
      Elemento *anterior = NULL; 
      while (atual != NULL && atual->valor < elemento->valor){ //navegar enquanto menor
          anterior = atual;
          atual = atual->prox;
      }

      if (atual == NULL){ //novo maior que todos
          nvlista->Fim->prox = elemento;
          nvlista->Fim = elemento;
      }
      else {
          if (anterior == NULL){ //novo menor que todos
              elemento->prox = nvlista->Inicio;
              nvlista->Inicio = elemento;
          }
          else {
              elemento->prox = anterior->prox;
              anterior->prox = elemento;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

[Veja o programa com estas alterações a funcionar corretamente](https://ideone.com/5tX9hh)

Apenas uma pequena nota em relação à escrita, evite escrever algo como `Lista*nvlista` tudo junto pois fica mais difícil de ler, e até pode dar ideia que é uma multiplicação. Opte por separar com espaço como é padrão escrevendo por exemplo `Lista *nvlista`.